# Geo location only working on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, html, geolocation

I have successfully implemented geo-location into my website on localhost. however upon uploading the website to an online server, it doesn't work anymore. i get a **bool(false)** error.

**Geo.php**

```
<?php 

      class Geo{

      protected $api = 'http://www.telize.com/geoip/%s';

      protected $properties = [];


      public function __get($key){

      if (isset($this->properties[$key])){
       return $this->properties[$key];
        }
      return null;
         }


      public function request($ip){

        $url = sprintf($this->api, $ip);
        $data = $this->sendRequest($url);
        $this->properties = json_decode($data, true);
            }

       protected function sendRequest($url){
       $curl = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       return curl_exec($curl);
          }

              }
                 ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  include ("functions/functions.php");

  $ip = getIp();

  require 'Geo.php';
  $geo = new Geo;
  $geo->request('$ip');
  $location = $geo->city . ',&nbsp' .$geo->region;

  ?>
```

getIp() function is located in the function.php file which i included, that works fine so I've excluded it.

Comment: what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: @jcuenod, it just echos out: bool(false), Doesn't say what line.

Comment: Note that,  `$geo->request('$ip');` will pass the string $ip and not the value of that variable. Use `$geo->request($ip);` instead

Comment: @Stefan, still didn't work

Comment: is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: what is in your `$ip` variable? Echo it out right after setting it and check.

Comment: @ jcuenod, its my ip address. works fine

Comment: @chris94 and for good purposes, check if `curl_exec($curl);` doesn't return false before trying to decode it. I will put you a code improvement in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Code improvement.

Geo.php

```
<?php 

class Geo {

    protected $api = 'http://www.telize.com/geoip/%s';
    protected $properties = [];

     public function __get($key)
     {
         if (isset($this->properties[$key]))
             return $this->properties[$key];

         return null;
      }

      public function request($ip) {
          $url = sprintf($this->api, $ip);
          $data = $this->sendRequest($url);
          if($data !== false) $this->properties = json_decode($data, true);
          return ($data !== false);
      }

       protected function sendRequest($url) {
           $curl = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
           return curl_exec($curl);
       }

}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
  include ("functions/functions.php");

  $ip = getIp();

  require 'Geo.php';
  $geo = new Geo;
  if($geo->request($ip)) {
      $location = $geo->city . ',&nbsp' .$geo->region;
  }
  else {
    // Location not found
  }

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the improvement. i get location not found, so i guess it's failing to request the ip address, and i know for sure that the ip address is there as i have echo the variable $ip and its correct.

Comment: still nothing.  can suggest another method i could use to get user location?

Comment: @chris94 because your getIp function is not working outside of your local server/network.